Sequelize Adding Association Causes Always Alter
I am trying to add multiple associations to my project. Although, other tables do not giving this error or misusage effect these associations makes the project always alter.
db.option.hasMany(db.question, {
   as: "showIfSelectedOption",
   foreignKey: "questId",
 });
 db.question.belongsTo(db.option, {
   as: "showIfSelectedOption",
   //foreignKey: "questId"
 });

db.option.hasOne(db.question, {
  as: "defaultAnswerx",
  // foreignKey: "optionId"
});

db.question.belongsTo(db.option, {
  as: "defaultAnswerx",
  //foreignKey: "quetionId"
});

db.question.hasMany(db.option, {
  //as: "questions",
  as: "options",
  foreignKey: { allowNull: true, name: "servicequestionIxd" },
});

db.option.belongsTo(db.question, {
  as: "quests",
  foreignKey: { allowNull: true, name: "servicequestionIxdx" },
});


One question has many options
One question has one option as defaultOption
One question belongs to an option and one option hasMany question. If the selected option is chosen then show question. One option may affect to multiple question.

Tried to eliminate the wrong one but every single association works seperated. What could be the solution?
